# what is the linear minimum mean squared estimator for y given x of the shaded region?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

A 2D random point (x,y) is uniformly distributed on the shaded region of the figure. 
[image]
What is the linear MMSE estimator for y, given x?

This is what I have so far:

Since it's a linear estimator, I want my estimator to have a form as the following:
$$ \hat{y} = wx$$
Now I want to find $w$ with the least expected variance given x. So we want to find 
$$\mathbb{E}[(y - \hat{y})^2 | x]$$

If I compute this I get:
$$\mathbb{E}[(y - \hat{y})^2 | x]= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (y - wx)^2 p(y|x) dy$$
After some algebra, I get the following:
$$
w = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&{3 \over 4x} &&: 0 \le x < {1 \over 2} \\
&{1 \over 2x} &&: {1 \over 2} \le x \le 1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

and since we defined $ \hat{y} = wx$, we get
$$
\hat{y} = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&{3 \over 4} &&: 0 \le x < {1 \over 2} \\
&{1 \over 2} &&: {1 \over 2} \le x \le 1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

This result bothers me because, first off, it's not linear and they are the same as the expected value of y given x, $\mathbb{E}[y | x]$.

Instead, if I take the unconditional expected value of it:
$$\mathbb{E}[(y - \hat{y})^2]= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}(y - wx)^2 p(x,y) dydx$$
I get
$$ w = {3 \over 4}$$ 
and 
$$\hat{y} = {3 \over 4} x$$

Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: What's the exact problem statement? Your first estimator is piecewise linear if we consider functions of the form $\hat y=wx+b$.

Comment: (1) Often a linear estimator would be considered one of the form $y=wx + v$ for parameters $w$ and $v$.  (2) You haven't yet considered the distribution of $x$.

Comment: @whuber On (2), OP actually stated that $x,y$ is a uniformly distributed 2D variable.

Comment: @broncoAbierto I want to find a linear estimator $\hat{y} = wx$. The only reason I used piecewise is that we want to estimate least expected variance given $x$. So I thought I had to split it up into two different cases of $x$. Also wouldn't $\hat{y} = wx + b$ be an affine estimator and not linear estimator?

Comment: @bronco Yes, we can all see that.  The point is that a consideration of this fact will determine which answer is the right one.

Comment: @MoneyBall That is just a matter of convention. In analysis and other fields, a linear function is usually defined simply as $w^Tx+b$. Not in algebra, where it would violate the requisites for $b\neq 0$. In statistical inference (esp. machine learning), I've always seen the term "linear estimator" to refer to a function of the form $w^Tx+b$, so I would not worry. For that reason, I wanted to know how specific the problem statement was, to see if piecewise functions would be allowed.

Comment: @whuber Doesn't that automatically determine $p(x)$, considering that $p(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x,y)dy$?

Comment: @broncoAbierto I guess my question boils down to this: Is linear minimum mean squared estimation a conditional expectation of least variance or unconditional expectation of least variarnce? Because if it's conditional, i think piecewise is the right solution, otherwise, the second solution is the correct solution.

Comment: Piecewise linear does not qualify as linear and therefore cannot be the intended solution.

Comment: @whuber It's not piecewise linear, it's a linear function that depends on $x$ which is given.

Comment: For each value $\alpha$ of $X$, $E[Y\mid X = \alpha]$ is the estimate of $Y$ that has minimum variance among all estimates of $Y$ when $X=\alpha$, that is, this estimate has least conditional variance given this specific condition that $X$ happens to have value $\alpha$.  $E[Y\mid X]$, which is a function of $X$, not $Y$, is the random variable that minimizes $E[(Y -g(X))^2]$ over all choices of measurable functions $g\cdot)$. In general as well as in this specific case, $E[Y\mid X]$ is a nonlinear function (a step function in this case) and that it is a _piecewise_ linear function ----

Comment: ---- doesn't make it a linear function in the accepted sense of the term: piecewise linear, Yes, linear No.

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution to this problem can be found in the [Solutions to Problem Set 13, ECE 313, Fall 2008, University of Illinois](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2008/homework/HW13.pdf). The problem statement can be found [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2008/homework/PS13.pdf).  The linear MMSE estimate of $Y$ in terms of $X$ is
$$\hat{Y} = -\frac{4}{11}X + \frac{35}{44}.$$
As is generally accepted by statisticians and probabilists, a *linear* MMSE estimate is actually an *affine* estimate: the adjective "linear" means that the graph of the estimate is a straight line, and not "linear" in the linear algebra sense of $L(A+B) = L(A)+L(B)$ is the property that must hold for $L(\cdot)$ to be called a linear transformation.

Comment: Assuming that we are talking about "linear" in linear algebra sense, is the unconditional expectation of the variance(the second answer I wrote) the correct solution? If that is the case, we are not taking $x$(which is given) into consideration when we are computing our linear estimator

Comment: @MoneyBall Draw the line and try to figure out if it is a good estimate.

Comment: (+1).  MoneyBall, when you leave out the constant term, then indeed $\hat y = 3x/4$ is the least-squares solution.